# Microsoft Access to web based format dynamically

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, web-applications, ms-office

I am sure there is a solution out there, but have not been able to locate anything that achieves the exact specifications I need.

I am looking for a web based script/application that can convert a MS Access database to text/csv any form of readable file.

The reason I need it to be web based is that our management currently uses an access database software package to create and track user data.  They export a subset of the tables required for user registration (via a mdb type saved as a different extension).  This is currently processed through the software providers website.  The problem being that the software provider no longer provides developmental support for the registration forms.

We do not wish to change the entire foundation of the Access database and if at all possible I just want to provide a solution that opens and converts the uploaded file (mdb type) and converts it to a text schema, or anything really that will enable us to dynamically generate web based forms for the tables uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you certainly could cobble together something yourself.

However the hosted web site would for all practical purpose have to be running something like ASP.net and ALSO support the reading of mdb/accdDB files.

I mean most web sites that support the JET/ACE database engine in 99% of the same cases also support .net code.

If you're running your own web server and especially asp.net then this should be no problem.

However you don't mention if this is your own web server or a hosted one? And you don't mention what kind of hosting you have?

Remember your web site runs on a computer. That computer could be a Mac computer, a windows computer or Linux. And you simply install software + programs onto that computer like a desktop computer.

If that computer is Linux based then you not going to be able to install say your vb.net software on that web site. So what kind of computer and OS your web site is running on will DETERMINE what kind of software it will run.

If your site is currently an asp.net hosted site and they support reading of Access files (has support for JET/ACE) then I don't see why a bit of vb.net (or c#) application could not be written with little effort to have that file uploaded and then the contents read.

I think before go looking for some software to do such a conversion I would FIRST find out and figure out what computer platform your web site is running on now. You THEN need to find out if that computer hosting the web site has support for JET (now called ACE) data engine.

It is a walk in the walk in the park to have some code open + read the mdb or accDB file and send that data to the web sites SQL server. However you can ONLY do this if your site in question has support for the JET/ACE database engine. (or you have your own server and you are ALLOWED to install the JET/ACE engine).

So a solution program (off the self) does exist then AGAIN 9 out of 10 times such a solution will REQUIRE that the JET/ACE engine be installed on your hosted web site.

So just keep in mind that like windows or Mac computer or even a tablet computer – the web server is EXACTLY the SAME in regards to WHAT software will run on that web site.

So without knowing what kind of web hosting you have then it becomes rather hard to suggest a working solution  that will be able to run + be installed on  your web site since we don't even know what kind of software can be installed on your web site now?

If you current web hosting does not allow the JET/ACE data engine to be installed it is VERY unlikely that EVEN if you found some software that does a conversion for you then such software will NOT install on your existing web site.

Any competent asp.net developer should with quite ease allow one to select a local mdb file, upload to server and then have web code open up the mdb file and pull out table data to sql server.

The only real thing stopping this process is as noted what kind of web server you have and what kind of software it will run.

Keep in mind the issue is OFTEN what kind of software you can install on the web server.

Just about every web provider allows managed code (c# or vb.net) code to be up-loaded on the server to be run. However installing NON managed code like the JET/ACE database engine is a VERY VERY different matter.

Starting point:
You need a web provider that supports the JET/ACE database engine or you need to be running your own web server that allows you to install the JET/ACE database engine.

Furthermore how would the software you install know the table names in Access and also know the table names in SQL server and also where to send the data?

At the end of the day all of the software bits and parts rather common exist if you have your own ISS server with  asp.net. And if your provider is using asp.net AND ALSO supports JET/ACE then AGAIN you have all the  software required.

As such then your code can use ftp or even HTTP to upload that file. All of these features are built into the .net framework assuming your web hosting provider allows asp.net + JET/ACE.

Comment: Thanks very much for the informative response.  I have control over the server architecture so can install the required components to get it functioning.  we don't run .net unfortunately (at the moment anyway), but I beleive the JET/ACE database engine may be able to be run through COM extensions in PHP.  Either way I am now well informed to be able to follow up a solution, thank you for the great response!

Comment: You are welcome. The JET database is ONLY going to install on your web server if that web server is running windows. JET will not install on a non windows platform or non windows box. These days if you running windows then you are running IIS and if you running IIS then you 99% of the time going to have support for .net. PHP can use JET this still suggests you going to be running IIS and thus windows. If you running .net then in the .net frame work is a FTP up loader and the ability to open + read the mdb (or accdb) file anyway. JET already is installed but you need ACE for accdB files.